# Hampering website parsing by adding useless data inside actual data

Tags: web-scraping, html-parsing, data-security

I want to prevent or hamper the parsing of the classifieds website that I'm improving.

The website uses API with JSON responses. As a solution, I want to add useless data between my data as programmers will probably parse by ID. And not give a clue about it in neither JSON response body nor header; so they won't be able to distinguish it without close inspection.

To prevent users from seeing it, I won't give that "useless data" to my users if they don't request it explicitly by ID. From an SEO perspective, I know that Google won't parse the page with useless data if there isn't any internal or external link.

**How reliable would that technic be? And what problems/disadvantages/drawbacks do you think can occur in terms of *user experience or SEO*?** Any ideas or suggestions will be very much appreciated.

P.S. I'm also limiting big request counts made in a short time. But it doesn't help. That's why I'm thinking of this technic.

I think banning parsers won't be better because they can change IP and etc.
Maybe I can get a better solution by requiring a login to access more than 50 item details for example (and that will work for Selenium, maybe?). Registering will make it harder. Even they do it, I can see these users and slow their response times and etc.

Comment: Why not use reCAPTCHA? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: @ghoti Recaptcha won't work if person uses a library that doesn't load Javascript. And most of them use these types of libraries. Also, they send GET request directly to the api endpoint which is just a JSON response without any JS

Comment: OK so the parsing is being performed from API output, not information served on a webpage. The problem becomes distinguishing genuine users from bots. Would this be a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555051/how-can-i-prevent-bots-and-spam-api-requests

Comment: No, these answers don't help me. My question is different than that